# How to call methods in Frida Gadget (JavaScript API iOS)?

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging, frida

i have class [ClassName] and method [- setSomething].

How can i call with JS API withount Interceptor this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function:

```
function modify_implementation(class_name, method_name, functions) {
    try {
      var methodObj = ObjC.classes[class_name][method_name]
      var old_implementation = methodObj.implementation;

      methodObj.implementation = ObjC.implement(methodObj, function () {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments); // modifying Arguments object into array

        if(typeof functions['arguments'] === 'function') {
          functions['arguments'](args);
        }

        var result = old_implementation.apply(null, args);

        if(typeof functions['result'] === 'function') {
          result = functions['result'](result);
        }

        return result;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('[!] Error while hooking ' + class_name + ' [' + method_name + ']', err);
    }
}
```